# What happen when in 3 way handshake, Server did not get client's ACK message?

Tags: networking, tcp

I understand that the client and the server are connected after client receives SYN ACK messages from the server during 3 way handshake and sending ACK messages to the Server. After they are connected, when the client sends the other messages to the server, what happens if that messages arrives at the server before the ACK message that client sent when doing the 3 way handshake?

Comment: It retransmits the SYN-ACK under the usual rules.

Answer (score 1):

> what happens if that messages arrives at the server before the ACK message that client sent when doing the 3 way handshake?

ACK is just the flag in the TCP header together with the sequence number of the latest received data. It can be contained in an empty packet (i.e. no payload, just TCP header) but also in a packet with payload. It does not matter if a specific packet with an ACK is received as long as an ACK covering the data is received at all.

This means it is sufficient if the initial data send by the client cover the final ACK for the TCP handshake. In fact there is not even a need to send a standalone ACK (without payload) from the client at all to finish the TCP handshake but the client can start sending data as soon as the client has received the SYN and ACK from the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. So you mean the server doesn't care if the ACK sent by client to server(end of 3 way handshake) is lost?

Comment: No, he means that it can be piggybacked onto the first data sent.